# Android Oreo WideColorGamut / ProPhotoRGB not recognised

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I exported a JPEG image with "RommRGB:ISO 22028-2:2013" color profile (in Mac / Affinity Photo) and put it into res/drawable-nodpi. Unfortunately the image will be not correctly recognised by Android Oreo.

```
...
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img_01_rommrgb, opts);

Log.i(TAG, "ColorSpace = " + opts.outColorSpace.getName());    // ===>  ColorSpace = Unknown

opts.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img_01_rommrgb, opts);

ColorSpace colorSpace = b.getColorSpace();           // ===>  Unknown
Bitmap.Config config = b.getConfig();                // ===>  ARGB_8888
...
```

I also downloaded a ProPhoto.icc and tried with that but I still get a "Unknown" ColorSpace. I also tried to put the image into the res/drawable-widecg-nodpi but still no success.

I think, the correct behavior would be:

1. Color space should be recognised correctly
2. Bitmap should be loaded in RGBA_F16

Maybe I am using the wrong color profile in Affinity Photo. I have no further ideas. Any help is appreciated.

ps: [I reported the issue by google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67853908)

**EDIT1**

I created a GitHub project to demonstrate the problem:
[Wide-gamut color test](https://github.com/piszoka/WideGamutColorTest)

I think, the following test cases are not correctly handled by Android Oreo:

- 1-d) Romm RGB
- 1-e) ProPhoto RGB
- 2-d) Romm RGB
- 2-e) ProPhoto RGB
- 3-d) Romm RGB
- 3-e) ProPhoto RGB
- 4-d) Romm RGB
- 4-e) ProPhoto RGB

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Android Oreo. I reported it as a bug to Google, and they asked for a sample app that would demonstrate the problem. Writing the app led to my understanding of actual problem. A beta version of the app is now available on Google Play as "Color Space Converter".

The ExifInterface class does not define a tag for ProfileDescription, which made the discovery of the actual problem a bit more difficult. When you attempt to create a bitmap for a file that uses any of the tags listed above, it fails with the Color.id equal to ColorSpace.MIN_ID. The only tag that works is "ROMM RGB ISO 22028-2:2013". In Gimp and exiftool, this tag appears as "Google Skia", for the Skia graphics engine.